# How to handle multiple numeric datasets for calculation?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

How do I handle technically a "table" of data which is depending on the age of a person? This data should be used for further calculations.

I would handle it with an object array, but I don't know how to look up for specific values.

*Example 'table' data*

```
age  | L     | M     | S
60   | -1.10 | 19.05 | 0.12
...
```

There would be nearly one hundred values and I need to get the values to do some more calculations with the L, M and S values.

```
const result = doSomeCalc(60) // pass age as param

doSomeCalc (age) => {
  // but how do I get the values for the given age from my 'table'?
  return l * s + m 
}
```

Comment: I think the best would be to make it into an array using multiple [`string.split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Comment: Can you post a sample javascript array or string, instead of the data format you have shown

Comment: If there are only a hundred values, would it be possible to just convert the data to a more JS friendly format? (e.g. JSON)

Comment: @DBS Yes, that would be possible, but I don't know which format I should use... That's why I talked about an object array `[{l: -1.10, m: 19.05, s: 0.12}]` But that would not handle the age.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would transform your "table" to `array` of `objects`.

```
users = [
    //...
    {age: 60,l: -1,m: 19,s: 12},
    {age: 50,l: -2,m: 20,s: 14}
]
```

if you want all users with specific age I would `filter` array;

```
const result = doSomeCalc(60);

doSomeCalc (age) => {
  let usersWithAge = users.filter((user)=> user.age===age);
  let result = 0;
  usersWithAge.forEach((user)=>{
    result += user.l * user.s + user.m
  });
  return result 
}
```

Or if you want one user with specific age I would `find` in array;

```
const result = doSomeCalc(60);

doSomeCalc (age) => {
  let userWithAge = users.find((user)=> user.age===age);
  return userWithAge.l * user.s + user.m
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way (`O(1)`) is to access the data by a key in an object (a.k.a dictionary). If you can transform your data structure to `age: { l, s, m }` scheme, you can just access the needed `l,s,m` params via `data[60]`, so it will be persistent Array-like data structure. If you are 100% sure that you have no gaps in ages (so you have all ages from 0 to 60), and that would not change, you can use regular array